# adding a value to body onload in xsl

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have an xsl which i am converting to html on client side.As i need to wait for the entire javascript to load hence I have given:

```
         <body onload="setTimeout(MyInitializeFunction, 1000);"
```

This works fine with other browser but IE doesnt support setTimeout.So After googling i found the solution is to wrap it inside function like this:

```
        <body onload= "setTimeout(function(){MyInitializeFunction();}, 1000);"
```

Error:Now it says MyInitializeFunction is an Unknown XSLT function.
Note:I have tried reading from an xml file after enclosing it in CDATA,but with no use.

```
body onload='&lt;xsl:value-of select="teststrings/MyInitializeFunctionVariable" disable-output-escaping="yes" /&gt'
```

It should be simple but what is that i am missing??????Plz help folks.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the braces: `<body onload= "setTimeout(function(){{MyInitializeFunction();}}, 1000);">`, that should fix the problem with XSLT. Why you think that in IE with Javascript `setTimeout(MyInitializeFunction, 1000)` would not work while `setTimeout(function() {MyInitializeFunction();}, 1000)` should work I am not sure, both calls pass a function object to `setTimeout`. In very old browsers you could only pass in a string with code, as in `setTimeout('MyInitializerFunction();', 1000)`, so that might be more likely to fix any Javascript errors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Martin... The reason for using the above way was because IE9  was not working with the above method.I really dont know why... Now althouh the syntax issue is resolved but body onload doesnt accept   setTimeout(function(){{MyInitializeFunction();}}, 1000);It throws the error MyInitializeFunction is not defined.. Any workaround  for this???

Comment: Well where is that function defined, is it defined correctly? We can only help debug code if we see it.